# C# WebClient UploadValues Stuck

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, webclient

I am trying to post data on API But looks like it stuck at line webClient.UploadValues on Amazon Cloud Windows Machine, it's working fine on Local Windows Computer, But not working on AWS Windows machine it stuck, is there different architecture or any additional settings needed to run it on AWS windows machine.

> ```
>   foreach  (string filename in filePaths)
>             {
>                 string payload = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename);
>                 using (WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
>                 {
>                     var _postParams = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
>                     webClient.Headers.Add("headertoken", Common._WebAPIKey);
>                     byte[] responseByes = webClient.UploadValues(Common._APIURL, "POST", payload);
>                     _returnValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseByes);
>                 }
>                 _filename = filename;
>                 System.IO.File.Delete(filename);                    
>             }
> ```

Comment: What do you mean "it's stuck"?  Are you getting an error or any HttpStatus codes back, like a 403?

Comment: Thanks for comment, No response, it was just hang/freeze at line webClient.UploadValues line, I noticed very strange issue, after restarting server issue was resolved automatically.

Comment: Glad it's solved; but that's crazy you solved it by rebooting the machine!

Comment: Yes i suspect it was something related to IO as my software was installed on Amazon T2 Micro Instance.